# WebClient failing for large file uploads. IIS configuration

Tags: web-server, iis-7, iis-8

To give a background, I am using `IIS8` and I have a `WCF` service that my `WinForms` client uses for all the work. I also have a `webclient` which uses the `uploadFile` and `DownloadFile` methods.
i had this piece of code added to my web config.

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="51200" executionTimeout="600" />
```

Everything was working fine when suddenly one day I uploaded a file that was close to 43 MB and it gave me a `404 (Not found) error`. I could find some solution on stack overflow and added this other bit of code to the web config as it was IIS7 and later.

```
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <requestFiltering>
                <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="51200000"></requestLimits>
            </requestFiltering>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
```

That solved the problem of the `404 error` but now i get the error which says

```
The request was cancelled. The request was aborted.
```

I know the problem is because of the `httprequest` timeout, but I am not able to figure out where i can configure it. The `executionTimeout` has been set but my process quits after 90 secs which is the default. I have tried the `KeepAlive` for the request but even that doesnt help.

It would be really helpful if the change could be possibly made on the config and not the client code. Is there a way to do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you set the exectionTimeout within the web.config of the wcf service?  WCF has a method to set via config for timeout.  Here is a link describing in more detail

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733051.aspx